# How does uboot print information during board bring up

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, bootloader, u-boot

During bootup of the target board we see uboot (bootloader) printing some information such as Image name, Image type, Load Address, Verifying checksum etc on the console. Which printing mechanism does it use? Does it use something like `printk` or it has its own definition for printing info even before kernel boots up? Where can I find the code for its printing implementation?

Comment: Basically U-Boot prints messages to serial console via UART. It has internal API to do so. Of course, before writing to UART, U-Boot needs to initialize (configure) it first. This is pretty much the same as kernel does. For better understanding of internals, you can look into my shrunk (minimal) version of U-Boot, which is only capable of writing to UART: https://gitlab.com/joeskb7/dra7xx-hello/tree/master

Comment: @samprotsenko Thank u for the uboot code. But my UART is ttyHS and baudrate is 757000. Can I use your uboot code in kernel for early printing functionality in kernel?

Comment: That code is just for a reference. No, you can't use it, because it's strictly architecture dependent (works only for one platform, which is probably not the same as you have). Basically, I just wanted to show you how printing is actually done in U-Boot, under the hood. You can look for serial console driver for your platform (in U-Boot), and investigate how it works. Functions like `debug()` and `printf()` are common for all architectures, but in the end they all rely on your serial console driver, which is specific to your platform.

Comment: Is there some actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

In the normal U-boot boot process,a limited amount of information is printed to the console. It use the the same kind of functions to print information as we use during the C programming.

u-boot use **`printf`** and **`puts`** to print the information on the console. you can find the same function implementations in the u-boot source code (u-boot boardfile and drivers).

There are a lot of commands which you can try from [u-boot](http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/90000852_K.pdf) command prompts for more information.

To enable more messages you can either:

- Using `debug_cond (cond, fmt, args...):` if you define some cond, once it is met, the U-boot will print out this message.
- Using `debug(fmt, args...):` you can define DEBUG in the file u-boot-`include/configs/<boardfile>_common.h` (like in my case mx6_common.h), once do that and recompile the code, the U-boot will print out all debug message

***Note:***  If you put too much debug into the code, it might make u-boot hang up.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter uBoot when you startup (interrupting the startup of the kernel) if you want information about uBoot for example where it prints to or what the values are of it's variables you can use the 'printenv' command and change them with the 'setenv' command.